# Why can I create but not write to a file from a Bash script within a cronjob?

Tags: bash, sed, cron

I have a simple Bash script that runs from the command line fine. It needs to write to two temp files near the beginning of the script. When I stick it in a cronjob, it will create the temp files, but will not write any data to it. The files are left with a zero size to them. Every time the cron job restarts, I want the temp files overwritten.

The cron entry basically looks like this:

```
0 */4   *   *   *   /opt/myscripts/boringScript.sh
```

In the script is:

```
...
echo "Starting boring inventory script"  >>  /opt/myscripts/boringScriptLog.out

countingScript.sh | grep $paramONE | sed s#\ ##g  >  tempResults1.txt
countingScript.sh | grep $paramTWO | sed s#\ ##g  > tempResults2.txt


do 
   // more stuff with the above temp files
   ...
done
...
```

Any ideas why it won't write any data to my temp files within the cron?

Thanks!

Comment: You should specify the complete path to `countingScript.sh`.  If it's in your home directory, you may still need to specify the path with `./countingScript.sh` or `~/countingScript.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not write to your tempResults files because of one of the two reasons:

1. The userid running the countingScript.sh, doesn't have write permission to those files
2. The userid running the countingScript.sh, doesn't have write rights in the directory it runs.

when you are dealing with cron, it is a very, but very-very good idea to specify absolute paths to all your scripts and files that you read from or write to. I do not see it in your script entirely.

For instance you are specifying the full path for the `/opt/myscripts/boringScriptLog.out`, but relying on countingScript.sh, tempResults1.txt and tempResults2.txt  to be in your current working directory and your user having write access to those.

Since the script is running, you at least have the read and execute permissions to the directory where your countingScript.sh resides but not write permissions.

Try using

```
/path/to/my/countingScript.sh | grep $paramONE | sed s#\ ##g  >  /tmp/tempResults1.txt
/path/to/my/countingScript.sh | grep $paramTWO | sed s#\ ##g  >  /tmp/tempResults2.txt
```

and modify the path to those tempResults files in the rest of your script where you reference them. You will be surprised to see them work beautifully.

Comment: Actually I had the full temp file path in my real script, but not for the countingScript.sh.  Changing that and adding a source /root/.bash_profile got it working. Thanks user854 and dg99!   ...but if I can run countingScript.sh from the command line (without the full path) as the root user anytime, does that mean running things through cron doesn't run the script with the same environment as root?